# Basic sub-vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

I have just begun studying vector-spaces and I'm trying to do this exercize :

Among those sets, which are sub-vector spaces ?

$E_{1}=${${(x,y,z) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^3; x=0}$}

1)$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_{1}$

2)Let $u=(x1,y1,z1) \ \in \ E_{1}$ so $x1=0$

Let $v=(x2,y2,z2) \ \in \ E_{1}$ so $x2=0$

So $\lambda u + v =(\lambda x1+x2, \lambda y1+y2, \lambda z1+z2)$

Thus the proof is finished like x1=x2=0 then $\lambda x1+x2=0$ whatever the value of  $\lambda$, and $\lambda u+v \ \in E_{1}$ thus $E_{1}$ is a sub-vector space.

$E_{2}=$ { $ (x,y,z) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^3; x=y+z $}

1)$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_{2}$

Let $u=(x1,y1,z1) \ \in \ E_{2}$ so $x1=y1+z1$

Let $v=(x2,y2,z2) \ \in \ E_{2}$ so $x2=y2+z2$

So $\lambda u + v =(\lambda x1+x2, \lambda y1+y2, \lambda z1+z2)=(\lambda y1+ \lambda z1 + y2 + z2 , \lambda y1 + y2 , \lambda z1 + z2)$ after replacing x1 and x2 by $y1+z1$ and $y2+z2$. We have $\lambda y1+ \lambda z1 + y2 + z2=  \lambda y1 + y2 + \lambda z1 + z2$ thus $\lambda u+v \ \in E_{2}$ thus $E_{2}$ is a sub-vector space.

$E_{3}=$ { $ (x,y,z) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^3; (x-y)(y-z)=0 $ }

$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_{3}$

Let $u=(x1,y1,z1) \ \in \ E_{.}$ so $(x1-y1)(y1-z1)=0$

Let $v=(x2,y2,z2) \ \in \ E_{2}$ so $(x2-y2)(y2-z2)=0$

So $\lambda u + v =(\lambda x1+x2, \lambda y1+y2, \lambda z1+z2)= (\lambda y1 +y2, \lambda y1+y2, \lambda z1 + z2)$ like $x1-y1=0$ then $x1=y1$ and $x2=y2$ and we have $(\lambda y1 +y2)-(\lambda y1 +y2))*(\lambda y1 +y2 -(\lambda z1 + z2))=0$ thus $\lambda u+v \ \in E_{3}$ thus $E_{3}$ is a sub-vector space.

$E_{4}=$ { $ (x,y,z) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^3; x \geq y $ }

$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_{4}$

Let $u=(x1,y1,z1) \ \in \ E_{4}$ so $x1 \geq y1$

Let $v=(x2,y2,z2) \ \in \ E_{4}$ so $x2 \geq y2$

So $\lambda u + v =(\lambda x1+x2, \lambda y1+y2, \lambda z1+z2)$ And like $x1 \geq y1$ and $x2 \geq y2$ we have necessarily $\lambda x1+x2 \geq \ \lambda y1+y2$ so $\lambda u+v \ \in E_{4}$ thus $E_{4}$ is a sub-vector space.

$E_{5}=$ { $ (x,y,z) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^3; x^2+y^2=0 $ }

$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_{5}$

Let $u=(x1,y1,z1) \ \in \ E_{5}$ so $(x1)^2+(y1)^2=0$ so x1=0 and y1=0

Let $v=(x2,y2,z2) \ \in \ E_{4}$

So $\lambda u + v =(\lambda x1+x2, \lambda y1+y2, \lambda z1+z2)$ And like $(x1)^2+(y1)^2=0$ and same thing for v we have  $\lambda x1+x2=0$ and $\lambda y1+y2=0$ so $\lambda u+v \ \in E_{5}$ thus $E_{5}$ is a sub-vector space.

Are my answers correct ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E_4$ isn't a subspace. Given $(x, y ,z)$ with $x \geq y$, it's not the case that $-1(x, y, z) = (-x, -y, -z) \in E_4$, as $-x \leq -y$.

Also, $E_3$ isn't a subspace either; it's not a linear piece of $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we just know that $(x - y)(y - z) = 0$, we can't say that $x = y$ **and** $y = z$, only that at least one of those is true. To show it isn't a subspace, pick two points, one where $x_1 = y_1$, and one where $y_2 = z_2$. Then check their sum.